# How can I check if ships are overlapping in battleships game? Confused with algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm not a great programmer so I was wondering if someone could help me. In my battleships game I have ships made from the Rect class, but I need to check if they are overlapping. This is what I have so far.

EDIT: What exactly is wrong: I have two ships one of size 2 and 5. So say ship 1 has (0,0)(0,1) coordinates and ship 2 has (0,1) to (5,1).It works great for checking both coordinates of ship one on point(0,1), but that is it. I hope this make sense. so if I check (0,0) and (0,1) on (1,1) it shows no eror

```
   public boolean contains(Ship ship) {
    int currentX = ship.getX();
    int currentY = ship.getY();
    int testX = xCoord;
    int testY = yCoord;

    if (rotated) {      //if ship is horizontal enter
        for (int j = 0; j < sizeOfShip; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < ship.getSize(); k++) {
                if (testX == currentX && testY == currentY) {
                    return false;
                }
                testX++;
            }
            if (ship.rotated)
                currentX++;
            else {
                currentY++;
            }
        }
    }
    //
    if (!rotated) {
        for (int j = 0; j < sizeOfShip; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < ship.getSize(); k++) {
                if (testX == currentX && testY == currentY) {
                    return false;
                }
                testY++;
            }
            if (ship.rotated)
                currentX++;
            else {
                currentY++;
            }           }
    }
    return true;

}
```

Comment: What happens when you run this? Why doesn't it work?

Comment: I have two ships one of size 2 and 5. So say ship 1 has (0,0)(0,1) coordinates and ship 2 has (0,1) to (5,1).It works great for checking both coordinates of ship one on point(0,1), but that is it. I hope this make sense. so if I check (0,0) and (0,1) on (1,1) it shows no error

Comment: you seem to not be doing anything with j & k in those for-loops, right?

Comment: I could not understand what the function supposed to find... And, in size 5 is (0,1) to (4,1), NOT (5,1).

Comment: You don't have to mark your changes with `EDIT`. There's an edit history kept here automatically. (See the link attached with `edited` below your question text.)

Comment: My apologies guys. Yes it is 0,1 to 4,1 mena, I'll change that now. d'alar'cop: I needed a way to increment the squares I was checking at the time, but no im not using j and k. Wow I don't know why I didn't put my other variables in the for loop. Let me try that now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem lies here (the same goes for the other `if`):

```
...
    testX++;
 }
 if (ship.rotated)
     currentX++;
 else {
     currentY++;
 }
 ...
```

I assume `testX` is `this` ships `x` value. You are incrementing `testX` in every iteration in the *inner* loop and the input parameters value (`currentX`) in the outer loop. At the same time you are never resetting the value. Lets say `this` ship have a length of 5 and the input parameter a length of 2 and both are horizontal. After 3 iterations of the outer loop `testX` have been incremented by 6.

I think you want to swap the increments around and reset the `currentX/Y` value after each inner iteration:

```
for (int j = 0; j < sizeOfShip; j++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < ship.getSize(); k++) {
        if (testX == currentX && testY == currentY) {
            return false;
        }
        if (ship.rotated)
            currentX++;
        else {
            currentY++;
        }
    }
    currentX = ship.getX();
    currentY = ship.getY();
    testX++;
}
```

This have to be done for both `if`s. I cannot try this, so try it out and tell me if I have made a mistake. :)

---

On a different note. You can replace

```
}
//
if (!rotated) {
...
```

with

```
}
else {
...
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that e.g. for a ship (0,1)(5,1) you need to check all the values (0,1)(1,1)(2,1)(3,1)(4,1)(5,1) against the all the other ship's similar values e.g. (0,0)(0,1) (no more since it's the small ship).

You need to modify your for-loops to do this for you. I suggest printing out those currentX/currentY values to make sure that they are doing this. In particular I don't think you want to be incrementing currentX/Y every iteration but rather currentX in one for-loop and currentY in the other.

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, it's appreciated

Comment: No worries mate. Do you reckon you could thumb this thing up?